# join 16 bits for color per pixel C#

Tags: c#

I have a question, I have a color (RGB) separated by 16bits per color, which I want to join to 64bits, for example:

```
R = 0x2222
G = 0xb1b1
B = 0x4c4c
A = 0x0000
```

How do I convert this to a single data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Are you familiar with the bitwise operators? And what is the expected output - e.g. what order should the bytes appear in?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want RGBA to appear in that order and about the operators something I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214497/combine-2-numbers-in-a-byte), but it does have a unique thing to trip you up, since you would otherwise left shift by more than 32 bits [and C# bafflingly only obeys the lower 5 or 6 bits in the shift amount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#shift-count-of-the-shift-operators). So, combining those two facts:

```
void Main()
{
    ushort r = 0x2222;
    ushort g = 0xb1b1;
    ushort b = 0x4c4c;
    ushort a = 0x0000;
    
    ulong rgba = r;
    rgba = rgba << 16; // each component is 16 bits long
    rgba = rgba | g;
    rgba = rgba << 16; 
    rgba = rgba | b; 
    rgba = rgba << 16; 
    rgba = rgba | a;
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{rgba:X}");
}
```

Comment: You can do it like this as well: `ulong rgba = (ulong)r << 48 | (ulong)g << 32 | (ulong)b << 16 | (ulong)a;` - If you don't cast to `ulong` first, then shifting would start losing bits, but that's not because of the 5/6 bit thing mentioned on that page, it's because it's shifting an `ushort` before it combines with `|`.

Comment: thanks @JoeSewell Just that I already have and your previous message served me a lot, that I am trying to store in a binary file.